# I am a beginner in SharePoint. What is the use of this code?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spservices

```
<div class="comnsection events">
    <div id="e1" class="tb-cont">
            <div class="scroll01" id="content-ltk2">
              </div>
            <div class="vall"><a id="lnkAnnoucementAll" href='javascript:void(0)'>View All</a></div>
          </div>    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        webURL:  $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite(),
        listName: "DPC_Announcements",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>", 
        CAMLRowLimit: 10,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            if (Status.toLowerCase() == "success") {
            $("#lnkAnnoucementAll").attr("href",  $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() + "/Lists/DPC_Announcements/AllItems.aspx")
                var Count = parseFloat($(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("rs:data").attr("ItemCount"));

                 if (Count != 0) {


                        announcementItems = '<ul>';
                           $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {

                            announceLink = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() + "/Lists/DPC_Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + $(this).attr("ows_ID");                                                        
                            announceTitle = $(this).attr("ows_Title"); 
                            announceDescription = $(this).attr("ows_Announcement_Description");    

                            announcementItems += '<li> <h5><a href="' + announceLink + '">' + announceTitle + '</a></h5>'+
                                                '<p>'+announceDescription.substring(0, Math.min(announceDescription.length, 250))+' <a href="'+announceLink +'">... more</a>'+ '</p></li>';
                           });
                         announcementItems += "</ul>";                        
                        $("#content-ltk2").html(announcementItems );

                    }



            }
        }
    });


 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The code that you have mentioned is used to fetch data from a SharePoint list named `DPC_Announcements`. It fetches the latest 10 items based on their created date and binds it to the `content-ltk2` div in HTML using jQuery. It uses the SPServices library to perform the **GetListItems** operation. It binds the Title and Description field and also gives you a link to the item page "Dispform.aspx" to redirect user to that item's details.